# private or no private (Maps, Sets, Lists...)

Tags: private

If you introduce new instance variables in the data field you use "private" like in

```
private int age;
private String name;
```

but when using Maps or Sets etc. you often don't use it, e.g.

```
 HashMap<String, String> students;
 Random ran;
```

Is there a general rule when you MUST use a "private"?

Comment: It might help if you at least tell us what language you are talking about.

Comment: I've never heard of such a rule. No modifier means "package protected" which means that classes in the same package can access it. Presumably other classes access `students` and `ran`, but this would have nothing to do with Maps, Sets, and Lists. It might help if you showed more code for context.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using java, the type of instance variable has nothing to do with whether you'd make it private or not.

You would make something private in a class if you only want it to be used in the class and not accessible outside of the class. Without a modifier (in java at least), it is 'package private', meaning that classes in the same package can access the variable, but classes in other packages cannot.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html for further information (and to learn about protected and public).